# How to perform element-wise multiplication with mathutils.Vector?

Tags: python

In Blender's I can add/subtract `mathutils.Vector` without any problems.

```
vec3 = vec1 - vec2  # OK return a vector
```

But! It's paint to multiply/divide vector. For example if i multiply vectors i'll get a float.

```
vec3 = vec1 * vec2  # ERROR return a float
```

Is there a method to multiply/divide vectors correctly? like `vec1.mult(vec2)` which exists in other game engines.

Comment: vec1.cross(vec2) returns the cross product **vec1 x vec2** and vec1.dot(vec2) returns the dot product **vec1 · vec2**.

Comment: Note, this is known as *"component-wise"* or *"element-wise"* multiplication, see:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32516/is-this-vector-operation-defined-does-it-have-a-name

Comment: @mifth, I'll look into adding element-wise-multiple, there doesn't seem to be a convention for this for object-oriented-Vector API's though, asked here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/277583/vector-api-naming-for-element-wise-multiply

Comment: @ideasman42 While I agree that v1.hadamard_product(v2) is overly verbose, how about simply v1.hadamard(v2) or v1.compwise(v2)?

Comment: @SixthOfFour, best move suggestions to the page linked.

Comment: @ideasman42 Regarding conventions for component wise multiplication of vectors: This is the default mode in GLSL. And I think it's a sane default. I found it very surprising that `mathutils.Vector` does not support this. You might argue that GLSL is not an object oriented API, but doesn't `numpy` also use this convention? [Source](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations#Operators)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a little bit of research, I concluded that the closest you can get is to use `mathutils.Vector.cross()` to do a cross multiplication of two vectors, or `mathutils.Vector.dot()` for dot multiplication; this info was gathered from [The API documentation](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73a_release/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector).

However, this doesn't seem to be the behavior you want - it seems you want to multiply the individual components of the vector, for which you can use something similar to this:

```
def mult(vec, vec2):
    temp = []

    for x, i in enumerate(vec):
        temp.append(i * vec2[x])

    return mathutils.Vector(temp)
```

Comment: Just curious: does anybody know why this is not mentioned in this source? ( https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.html ) To make it even more puzzling, it _is_ mentioned in the v2.44 documentation... Am I looking at the wrong package or something?

Answer (score 12):

I am amazed `mathutils.Vector` class does not support vector scaling by another vector!

This can be for example useful when you get scale vector from matrix decomposition and you want to scale other vectors accordingly.

This is with a generator expression for better performance:

```
vec3 = Vector(x * y for x, y in zip(vec1, vec2))
```

Comment: generator-expression is a little nicer then list-comprehension here, edited.

Comment: @ideasman42 good point!